# How to use regex to match the year with specific prefix?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How can I use regex in Python in order to extract **'year'** (but not other numbers) from the following text:

```
built:1999   blt 2002   BLT2005 Built: 2013    date: 1999, 23  das23
```

I don't want any other number, but just the those following `"Built/blt/BLT/Built/...)`

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d{4}', yourstring)`

Comment: Thanks, but this code returns every 4-digit number, while I want those which follow the mentioned pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> t = 'built:1999 blt 2002 BLT2005 Built: 2013 date: 1999, 23 das23'
>>> d = re.findall(r'((Built|blt|BLT|Built)((:?)( ?)))(\d{4})', t, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> [list(x)[5] for x in d]
```

Produces: `['1999', '2002', '2005', '2013']`

Comment: Thanks alot.It worked! could you also tell how would it work, In case:
1. there is also "/" and not just ":" (blt/2000) 2.  there is also a space before ":" or "/" (blt : 2000)

Comment: @NajmeRastegar Regex: `((Built|blt|BLT|Built)(( ?)(:?)(\/?)( ?)))(\d{4})`

Comment: I have already tried that. But by adding the new part "(\/?)( ?)", nothing will be returned!

Comment: What is the whole regular expression then? You can test the regular expression at http://regex101.com by the way.

Comment: I cannot make it, because I need sth that consider all these variations: "built: 1999  blt  2002 BLT2005 Built :2013 date: 1999, 23 das23 blt/1999 blt/ 2000 blt : 2000 built  /  2000"

Comment: @NajmeRastegar Regex: `(((B|b)(uilt|lt|LT|uilt))(( ?)(:?)(\/?)( ?)))(\d{4})`; Output it catches is: `built: 1999 blt 2002 BLT2005 Built :2013 blt/1999 blt/ 2000 blt : 2000 built / 2000`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
(?:[Bb](?:ui)?(?:[lL][Tt]))(?:[\:\s]*)?(\d+)
```

#### [Demo](http://regexr.com/3g7d4)